# Parameters in an Absolute Value Functions

Tags: functions

$$y_1=2|x+5|+|x-3|$$

$$y_2=2|x-1|+x+a$$

Looking for help. The question is to find "a" value, if functions intersect only two times.
My answer is that $a\in(2,4)$. Can anybody help with it?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How did you find that answer?

Comment: 1) functions plotting;

Comment: If $y=2|x-1|+x+a$ then saying $a=(2;4)$ makes no sense - here $a$ is a real number, not a vector.

Comment: Please show your work as to how you found (2,4). Also specify whether your solution is incomplete, or simply wrong.

Comment: 2) opened the absolute value, then go for system of equations

Comment: Hi @TomJK-st could you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4509018/edit) the question to include the comments made by you (copy-paste)?

Comment: I'm finding that $a \in (1,9)$.

Comment: According to ISO both ordered couples and intervals are designated as $(a,b)$.

Comment: Also, $a = 13$.

Comment: Consider four cases $x<-5$, $-5\leq x < 1$, $1\leq x < 3$ and $x\leq 3$. Find solution for each case and check which $a$ make this solution lying in the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: If $x \le -5$ then $y_1 = -3x -7$ and $y_2=-x+(2+a)$.

Solving $-3x-7=-x+(2+a) \implies x=\frac {-9-a}2$.  That's a single solution if $\frac{-9-a}2 \le -5$ or $a \ge 1$.

So if $a \ge 1$ there will be one solution where $x \le -5$.

Case 2: If $-5 < x \le 1$ then $y_1 = x+13$ and $y_2 =-x+(2+a)$.

Solving $x+13=-x+(2+a)\implies x = \frac{-11+a}2$. That's a single solution if $-5< \frac {-11+a}2 \le 1$ or $-10 < -11+a \le 2$ or $1 < a \le 13$

So if $1< a \le 13$ there will be solutions where $-5 < x \le 1$.

Case 3:  If $1 < x \le 3$ then $y_1 = x+13$ and $y_2 = 3x + (a-2)$.

Solving $x+13 = 3x+(a-2)\implies x=\frac {15-a}2$.  That's a single solution if $1< \frac {15-a}2 \le 3$ or if $9\le a < 13$.

Case 4:  If $x > 3$ then $y_1 =3x+7$ and $y_2 =3x+(a-2)$.

Solving $3x+7 = 3x+(a-2)$ will have no solutions if $a\ne 9$ and infinite solutions if $a=9$

Comining all cases

If $a < 1$ there are no solutions. None of the cases.

If $1\le  a < 9$ there will be two apparent solutions. Case 1 and Case 2.

If $a =9$ there will be infinite solutions.  Case 4, Case 1, and Case 2.

If $9< a \le 13$ there will be three solutions. Case 1, Case 2, Case 3.

If $a > 13$ there will be one solution. Case 1.

Why do I say apparent? Well, we must make show the solutions are distinct.

If $1 \le a < 9$ then the two solutions are $\frac {-9-a}2$ and $\frac {-11+a}2$.  Those are a single solution if $a=1$.

If $9 < a \le 13$ there there are three solutions $\frac {-9-a}2, \frac {-11+a}2,$ and $\frac {15-a}2$.  If $a=1$ (already considered), or if $a=13$ then two of these solution solutions are equal.  So if $a =13$ there are two solutions.

So, final answer:

If $a \in (1,9)\cup \{13\}$ there are two solutions.  If $a\in (1,9)$ the two solutions are $\frac{-9-a}2$ and $\frac{-11+a}2$.  If $a=13$ then the two solutions are $\frac {-9-a}2=-11$ and $\frac {-11+a}2 = \frac {15-a}2 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in applying graphical approach.

0. $a \in (-\infty,1)$, no solutions
1. $a = \{1\} \cup (13,\infty)$, 1 solution
2. **$\mathbf{a \in (1,9) \cup \{13\}}$, 2 solutions**
3. $a \in (9,13)$ 3 solutions
4. $a = 9$, infinitely-many solutions